# MSTest: why is TestOutcome = InProgress after ExpectedCondition?

Tags: mstest, expected-exception, testcontext

I have the following tryout code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VisibilitySucces()
{
    testPage.HideParagraph();
    testPage.ShowParagraph();
}

[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException))]
public void ShouldBeVisibleException()
{
    testPage.ShouldBeVisibleException();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
     switch (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome)
     {
         case UnitTestOutcome.Passed:
               Console.WriteLine("Passed!");
               break;
         default:
               Console.WriteLine("The test outcome is " + TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString());
               break;
     }
     Browser.Quit();
}
```

Now, the first test has the outcome `Passed` as expected.
The second test does throw the exception (I've tested it without the `ExpectedException` attribute). It's marked as passed visually, but the outcome in the console is showing `InProgress`.

How can this be when this status is queried in the `TestCleanup`?

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior in a simple case that just throws an exception.  Can you reproduce it without the webdrivertimeoutexception?  Do you have any timeouts set for your test run?